# Is there an overview of all SQL Server 2012 error codes?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, odbc, c++-cli

[SQLGetDiagRec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms716256%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) returns a native error code. Is there anywhere an overview of the error codes of SQL Server 2012? I couldn't find anything on MSDN.

Comment: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645603(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: @JuliusDepulla this link has been retired. Refer this link - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 12, accepted):

I'm unable to find a list of the individual codes in the internet. However I did find a list of the *severity levels* [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms164086.aspx) on MSDN. They are as follows:

Severity level / Description

- 0-9: Informational messages that return status information or report
  errors that are not severe. The Database Engine does not raise system
  errors with severities of 0 through 9.
- 10: Informational messages
  that return status information or report errors that are not severe.
  For compatibility reasons, the Database Engine converts severity 10
  to severity 0 before returning the error information to the calling
  application.
- 11-16: Indicate errors that can be corrected by the
  user.
- 11: Indicates that the given object or entity does not exist.
- 12: A special severity for queries that do not use locking because of
  special query hints. In some cases, read operations performed by
  these statements could result in inconsistent data, since locks are
  not taken to guarantee consistency.
- 13: Indicates transaction
  deadlock errors.
- 14: Indicates security-related errors, such as
  permission denied.
- 15: Indicates syntax errors in the Transact-SQL
  command.
- 16: Indicates general errors that can be corrected by the
  user.
- 17-19: Indicate software errors that cannot be corrected by the
  user. Inform your system administrator of the problem.
- 17: Indicates
  that the statement caused SQL Server to run out of resources (such as
  memory, locks, or disk space for the database) or to exceed some
  limit set by the system administrator.
- 18: Indicates a problem in the
  Database Engine software, but the statement completes execution, and
  the connection to the instance of the Database Engine is maintained.
  The system administrator should be informed every time a message with
  a severity level of 18 occurs.
- 19: Indicates that a nonconfigurable
  Database Engine limit has been exceeded and the current batch process
  has been terminated. Error messages with a severity level of 19 or
  higher stop the execution of the current batch. Severity level 19
  errors are rare and must be corrected by the system administrator or
  your primary support provider. Contact your system administrator when
  a message with a severity level 19 is raised. Error messages with a
  severity level from 19 through 25 are written to the error log.
- 20-24: Indicate system problems and are fatal errors, which means
  that the Database Engine task that is executing a statement or batch
  is no longer running. The task records information about what
  occurred and then terminates. In most cases, the application
  connection to the instance of the Database Engine may also terminate.
  If this happens, depending on the problem, the application might not
  be able to reconnect. Error messages in this range can affect all of
  the processes accessing data in the same database and may indicate
  that a database or object is damaged. Error messages with a severity
  level from 19 through 24 are written to the error log.
- 20: Indicates
  that a statement has encountered a problem. Because the problem has
  affected only the current task, it is unlikely that the database
  itself has been damaged.
- 21: Indicates that a problem has been
  encountered that affects all tasks in the current database, but it is
  unlikely that the database itself has been damaged.
- 22: Indicates
  that the table or index specified in the message has been damaged by
  a software or hardware problem. Severity level 22 errors occur
  rarely. If one occurs, run DBCC CHECKDB to determine whether other
  objects in the database are also damaged. The problem might be in the
  buffer cache only and not on the disk itself. If so, restarting the
  instance of the Database Engine corrects the problem. To continue
  working, you must reconnect to the instance of the Database Engine;
  otherwise, use DBCC to repair the problem. In some cases, you may
  have to restore the database. If restarting the instance of the
  Database Engine does not correct the problem, then the problem is on
  the disk. Sometimes destroying the object specified in the error
  message can solve the problem. For example, if the message reports
  that the instance of the Database Engine has found a row with a
  length of 0 in a nonclustered index, delete the index and rebuild it.
- 23: Indicates that the integrity of the entire database is in
  question because of a hardware or software problem. Severity level 23
  errors occur rarely. If one occurs, run DBCC CHECKDB to determine the
  extent of the damage. The problem might be in the cache only and not
  on the disk itself. If so, restarting the instance of the Database
  Engine corrects the problem. To continue working, you must reconnect
  to the instance of the Database Engine; otherwise, use DBCC to repair
  the problem. In some cases, you may have to restore the database.
- 24: Indicates a media failure. The system administrator may have to
  restore the database. You may also have to call your hardware vendor.

Answer (score 36):

```
use master
select * from sysmessages
```

Comment: Looking in the database to get the message is not really an option. Maybe the database isn't available anymore. So I really need a list of error codes that I can handle in the code.

Comment: The list of error messages in the database is a static list.  You can execute the query on an SQL Server install to see the full list of error codes and associated messages.  You can use the message_ids from that list in code to handle however you wish.

Answer (score 6):

I found the codes for MS SQL Server 2008 R2, but most of them are true for the later versions:
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc645603(v=sql.105).aspx

Comment: This link has been retired. Refer - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/errors-events/database-engine-events-and-errors?view=sql-server-ver15

Answer (score 3):

I was also looking for a list myself and found out that you could view them all from the master DB by running this statement:

```
SELECT * FROM sysmessages
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2005 and above you can use this:

```
SELECT * FROM sys.messages
```

As others have mentioned, you can also use (available in SQL Server 2000):

```
SELECT * FROM sysmessages
```